# C# Dev Kit shows tests that are not in my project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a C# project in vs code. It uses .net core 3.1. My solution consists of a C# mvc web app project and another project with MSTest unit tests. I have the C# dev kit extension installed. C# dev kit seems to pick up my unit tests correctly, and I can run them and everything works fine. But it is also picking up unit tests that are not found anywhere in either project. It must be because I copied this solution from an existing solution and then did a bunch of search/replace to get this new project going. C# dev kit is somehow finding the tests from the solution this one was copied from.

If I copy the entire project to a separate computer and compile it the old tests do not show up. I think that's a clue that it has nothing to do with anything in the solution or it's projects themselves.

Another clue: I have a saved workspace called "AssemblyDefectsWeb.code-workspace".  If I rename the workspace to "AssemblyDefectsWeb2.code-workspace" and open the solution that way, the tests from the old solution do not show up, only the tests from the current solution show up, which is good. As soon as I rename it back to the original, the old tests show up again!

C# Dev Kit seems to be caching something somewhere and I can't figure out how to clear that out. Can anyone help me find where this is and clear it out? It's not really hurting anything, and I can hide the tests. But it's driving me crazy that I can't figure out how to really remove them.

Comment: Maybe try deleting the hidden .vs folder for the solution?  Thats assuming it exists when using visual studio code.

Comment: Change to "C# DevKit - Test Explorer" in the Output Window. There should be Output what&where test are found. From there you then might find why.

Comment: People have no access to your machine and they cannot guess out what the old/new test cases look like or what might be wrong. So, if you cannot share more details, this remains vague.

Comment: That was a good idea Timothy G. and I thought that was gonna do it!  But nope, I deleted that and it didn't have an impact.

Comment: I'd suggest that you also raise an issue ticket. you can find existing bug tickets about the testing feature [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dotnettools/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3Aarea-test+label%3Abug). You can raise a new one [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dotnettools/issues/new?assignees=&labels=bug&projects=&template=bug.yml&title=%5BBUG%5D+%3Ctitle%3E). I see you found a workaround, but better not to let this get swept under the rug without the extension maintainers knowing about it. If you do raise a bug ticket, _please ping me here with a link to it!_

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how safe this is to do, but in my case I was able to fix the problem by cleaning out this folder:

```
C:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage
```